# Is it possible to write non-dynamic SQL that will match rows with a dynamic number of "attributes"?

Tags: sql

Imagine I have two tables.

```
Document
  int  DocumentId (PK)
  char DocumentName

Attribute
  int  DocumentId (FK)
  char AttributeName
  char AttributeValue
```

Can a non-dynamic select statement be written that will allow me to select out `DocumentName`s that match a set of `AttributeName`, `AttributeValue` pairs?

Comment: Can you provide an example with input data & expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- Use a table of name,value pairs to search for
DECLARE @wanted TABLE (AttribitedName ..., AttributeValue ...)

INSERT @wanted VALUES ('Colour', 'Blue')
INSERT @wanted VALUES ('Status', 'Draft')

SELECT
   *
FROM
   Document D
WHERE
   EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
             Attribute A
             JOIN
             Wanted W ON A.AttributeName = W.AttributeName AND A.AttributeValue = W.AttributeValue
        WHERE
             D.DocumentId = A.DocumentId
        -- do we match all terms that are in Wanted per DocumentID?
        GROUP BY
             A.DocumentId
        HAVING
             COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Wanted)
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent, fast answer! Is it possible to do this without a temp table?  I'm inclined to think not...